# Unable to get more details after clicking of list item.

Tags: android, json, listview, android-volley

Unable to get more details after clicking of list item. I am getting list view image with text from json .But i want after click on particular item , I want to get more details .
After clicking particular item, i am not getting further information.

i am stuck why i am not getting after clicking .
see in the image after clicking i am getting blank while i want to try set name ,image_url etc details

see the image of list view

[image]
[image]

Adapter->Customlist Adapter.java

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Movie> movieItems;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.movieItems = movieItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movieItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return movieItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        /*ImageView img;
        img = (ImageView)convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.img);

        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bc);
        else {*/

        NetworkImageView _ImageView = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
         _ImageView.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.bc);
        //NetworkImageView.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), ImageLoader);
        /*NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);*/
        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView average_ratings = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.average_ratings);
        TextView address=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.area);
        TextView cuisine =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cuisine);
        //TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        //TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);

        // getting movie data for the row
        Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

        // thumbnail image
        //_ImageView.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
        /*if (TextUtils.isEmpty(m.getThumbnailUrl()))
            thumbNail.setImageResource(R.drawable.bc);
    else
            //Log.d("KeyHash:","Neeraj");*/
        _ImageView.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
        /*if (m.getThumbnailUrl().compareTo("")!=0)
            thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
        //else{
        //thumbNail.setImageResource(R.drawable.bc);

            else {

                thumbNail.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.bc);
                //thumbNail.setErrorImageResId(R.drawable.bc);

        }*/


        // title
        name.setText(m.getName());

        // rating
        average_ratings.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(m.getAverage_ratings()));
        address.setText("Area: " + String.valueOf(m.getAddress()));
        cuisine.setText("Cusine: " + String.valueOf(m.getCuisine()));
        /*// genre
        String genreStr = "";
        for (String str : m.getGenre()) {
            genreStr += str + ", ";
        }
        genreStr = genreStr.length() > 0 ? genreStr.substring(0,
                genreStr.length() - 2) : genreStr;
        genre.setText(genreStr);

        // release year
        year.setText(String.valueOf(m.getYear()));*/

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Appcontroller.java

```
public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        getRequestQueue();
        if (mImageLoader == null) {
            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                    new LruBitmapCache());
        }
        return this.mImageLoader;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

mmodel- movie.java

```
public class Movie {
    private String name, thumbnailUrl;
    //private int year;
    private String average_ratings,area,cuisine,address;
//  private ArrayList<String> genre;

    public Movie() {
    }

    public Movie(String name, String thumbnailUrl, String average_ratings, String area, String cuisine, String address
            ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
        //this.year = year;
        this.average_ratings = average_ratings;
        this.area=area;
        this.cuisine=cuisine;
this.address=address;
        //this.genre = genre;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getThumbnailUrl() {
        return thumbnailUrl;
    }

    public void setThumbnailUrl(String thumbnailUrl) {
        this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
    }

    /*public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }*/

    /*public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }*/

    public String getAverage_ratings() {
        return average_ratings;
    }

    public void setAverage_ratings(String average_ratings) {
        this.average_ratings = average_ratings;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCuisine() {
        return cuisine;
    }

    public void setCuisine(String cuisine) {
        this.cuisine = cuisine;
    }
    /*public ArrayList<String> getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(ArrayList<String> genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }
*/
}
```

ListViewActivity.java

```
    public class ListViewActivity extends Activity {
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = ListViewActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    // change here url of server api
    private static final String url = "http://6c936eaa.ngrok.io/api/v1/restaurants?per_page=10&page=1&sort_col=average_ratings";

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;

    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Movie movie = movieList.get(position);
                // retrieve from movie whatever you want
                movie.getName();

                Intent intent = new Intent(ListViewActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
               TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
              //  name.setText(movie.getName());
                intent.putExtra("name",movie.getName());
                String name1 = intent.getStringExtra("name");
                name.setText(name1);
                startActivity(intent);
                intent.putExtra("param1",movie.getName());
                intent.putExtra("param2",movie.getName());
                intent.putExtra("param3",movie.getName());
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Name: "+movie.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
         pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Please Keep patience.Its loading...");

        pDialog.show();
        // changing action bar color
        //getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
              //  new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));
        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();
                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Movie movie = new Movie();
                                //movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                                movie.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                                //movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                                movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image_url"));
                                movie.setAverage_ratings(obj.getString("average_ratings"));
                                movie.setCuisine(obj.getString("cuisine"));
                                movie.setAddress(obj.getJSONObject("address").getString("area"));
                                movie.setCost(obj.getString("cost"));
                                //movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));
                                // Genre is json array
                                /*JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                                ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                                for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                    genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                                }
                                movie.setGenre(genre);*/
                                // adding movie to movies array
                                movieList.add(movie);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();

            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }



}
```

list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ly_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:background="#FEFEFE"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <!-- Restaurant name  -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/area"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/name"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:textColor="#D2691E"/>

        <!-- Rating -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/average_ratings"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/area"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:textColor="#D2691E" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cuisine"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/average_ratings"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:textColor="#D2691E" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



<!--
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     >
&lt;!&ndash;<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_row_selector"
    android:padding="8dp" >&ndash;&gt;

    &lt;!&ndash; Thumbnail Image &ndash;&gt;
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/ly_root"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FEFEFE"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">


    &lt;!&ndash;<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">&ndash;&gt;
    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"  />

    &lt;!&ndash; Restaurant name  &ndash;&gt;
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textSize="@dimen/title"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/area"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:textColor="#D2691E"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

    &lt;!&ndash; Rating &ndash;&gt;
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/average_ratings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/area"
        android:textColor="#D2691E"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"

        android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cuisine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/average_ratings"
        android:textColor="#D2691E"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

    &lt;!&ndash; Genre &ndash;&gt;
   &lt;!&ndash; <TextView
        android:id="@+id/genre"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/rating"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textColor="@color/genre"
        android:textSize="@dimen/genre" />&ndash;&gt;
&lt;!&ndash;
    &lt;!&ndash; Release Year &ndash;&gt;
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/releaseYear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="@color/year"
        android:textSize="@dimen/year" />&ndash;&gt;
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>-->
```

SecondActivity.java

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);
        TextView name1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        //name.setText(movie.getName());
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"name from second activity "+bundle.getString("name"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String name = bundle.getString("name");
   /* String param1 = bundle.getString("param1");
    String param2 = bundle.getString("param2");
    String param3 = bundle.getString("param3");*/
    }
}
```

SecondActivty.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: check below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this,**

**Add code for your `listView.setOnItemClickListener`**

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Movie movie = movieList.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(ListViewActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", movie.getName());
                intent.putExtra("rating", movie.getAverage_ratings());
                intent.putExtra("area", movie.getAddress());
                intent.putExtra("image_url", movie.getThumbnailUrl());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

**Add this in `SecondActivity.java`**

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

        // get value from intent
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String name = bundle.getString("name");
        String rating = bundle.getString("rating");
        String address = bundle.getString("area");
        String profileUrl = bundle.getString("image_url");

        // initialize view
        TextView txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView txtRating = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rating);
        TextView txtAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);
        NetworkImageView movieImage = (NetworkImageView)findViewById(R.id.movieImage);

        //set values to view
        txtName.setText(name);
        txtAddress.setText(address);
        txtRating.setText(rating);
        movieImage.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.bc);
        movieImage.setImageUrl(profileUrl, AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader());



        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"name from second activity "+bundle.getString("name"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

**Note:**
In your layout file you have to create `TextView` for **rating** and **address**
Similarly create `imageView` as you created for your `custom list`

Comment: i have to set image_url, avreage_ratings,cuisine ,area etc after clicking in second activity .

Comment: i have tried .i am getting by  default image .By default means i have set for when image url is not present. it will be shown . not getting original image .not getting rating as well as address .while i have set in layout .

Comment: Replace your `listView.setOnItemClickListener` with given one.

Answer (score 1):

Now best of luck.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(ListViewActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);                   
 Movie movie = movieList.get(position);

 intent.putExtra("name",movie.getName());
 intent.putExtra("url",movie.getThumbnailUrl());
 intent.putExtra("rating",movie.getAverage_ratings());
 intent.putExtra("add",movie.getAddress());
 intent.putExtra("cusine",movie.getCuisine());
 startActivity(intent);
```

SecondActivity.java

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);
        TextView name1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        //name.setText(movie.getName());
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        String name = bundle.getString("name");
        name.setText(name);
        String url = bundle.getString("url");
        String rating = bundle.getString("rating");
        String add = bundle.getString("add");
        String cusine = bundle.getString("cusine");
    }
}
```

Comment: image_url,avreage_ratings,cuisine ,area is coming from json . HOw to set in secondactivity after clicking . I am not getting .

Comment: @user6313669 have you try my answer.do you have teamviewer?

Comment: yes tried . i am getting only name in second activity . not getting all.yes i have TeamViewer with id 772 127 914.

Answer (score 0):

First set all your data after start your activity

```
intent.putExtra("name",movie.getName());
intent.putExtra("param1",movie.getName());
intent.putExtra("param2",movie.getName());
intent.putExtra("param3",movie.getName());
startActivity(intent);
```